# Advantages of database vs hash for simple key value lookup (in Ruby)

Tags: ruby, database, hash, amazon-dynamodb, key-value

Suppose I have a production app on AWS with, let's say 50,000 users, and I need to simply take a username and lookup one or two pieces of information about them.

Is there any advantage to keeping this information in a DynamoDB over a Ruby hash stored in an AWS S3 bucket?

By "advantages" I mean both cost and speed.

At some point, will I need to migrate to a DB, or will a simple hash lookup suffice? Again, I will never need to compare entries, or do anything but lookup the values associates with a key (username).

The more general question is: what are the advantages of a DB (like DynamoDB) over an S3 hash for the purposes of simple key/value storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that `Hash` cannot be used as database, it must be loaded with values from some data store (such as a database, a JSON, YAML file or equivalent).  On the contrary, DynamoDB is a database and has persistence built-in.

Having said that, for 50,000 entries, a Ruby Hash should be a viable option, it will perform quite well as indicated in [this article](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/hash-lookup-in-ruby-why-is-it-so-fast).

Ruby Hash is not distributed, hence, if you run your app on multiple servers for availability/scalability, then, you will have to load that Hash in each server and maintain its data consistency.  In other words, you need to make sure that if one of the user attributes gets updated via one server, how will you replicate its value across other server.  Also, if number of users in your system is not 50,000 but 50 million - then, you may have to rethink Hash as cache option.

DynamoDB is full blown [NoSQL database](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html) - it is distributed and promises high scalability. It also costs [money](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/) to use it - so your decisions to use it should be based on whether you need such a scale and availability offered by DynamoDB, and whether you have budget for it.

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped me clarify the question! I shouldn't have compared  `Hash` to a database. Rather, I should have been comparing using a Ruby hash stored (as JSON) in an S3 bucket to using DynamDB.

Comment: “You should note that Hash cannot be used as database, it must be loaded with values from some database.“ You could also store the data as YAML or JSON or as Marshaled data or CSV or...

Comment: @Jordan Will change "database" to "datastore".